# Is Ubuntu well-suited as a small business solution?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is Ubuntu well-suited as a small business solution? I have a very scared part time IT manager who thinks it's not suitable.  Please can you clarify?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This sort of discussion is a better fit for the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org).

Comment: a Scared IT manager? how dares he even touch a computer after saying that.. lmao

Comment: Does this IT manager know how to access the Internet? Direct him to this link: http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/resources/case-studies

Comment: I'll join in with a relevant link of my own: http://www.canonical.com/about-ubuntu/for-business

Comment: Additionally, this question could be improved if you provided specific concerns your IT manager has so we can properly address them. Why exactly is he against it?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, Well for one he knows nothing of Linux and two he says that Ubuntu is NOT suitable for a small business and should stay on home computers.  Then he goes on about 92% of the world is using Windows and where can you find Ubuntu Linux experienced people in the UK?? Well I work in Croydon, no more than 6 miles up the road is Canonical UK HQ.  Sad thing is he still has Vista on his laptop and is just updating to Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu is perfectly suitable for business use in general. To compare, Microsoft has different versions of Office directed at personal use and students and other versions for professionals. The software itself is pretty much the same, but with different restrictions. For instance, if you buy MS Office for personal use, you can't legally use it in your small business. Another example is Windows Small Business Server. This is just a bundle of Windows Server software with a limit to how many users you are allowed to have, etc. Because of these restrictions, the price of the software can be lowered because you couldn't use it for larger businesses.

With Ubuntu, there are no ultimate editions or personal use only editions. Everyone gets the best software available. I see no reason why LibreOffice should be more or less useful to large companies than it is to small businesses, students or personal users, for instance. We know for a fact that it is useful to very large companies and organizations. So, as a general answer to a general question, I would say that yes, Ubuntu is very much suitable for small businesses.

As a general advise, I'd recommend that you define your needs, rather than labeling yourself simply as a small business. There might be differences between a hair dresser and a small law firm, for instance.

Comment: Thank you Jo for your reply.  There is one or two specific reasons why windows must stay and that is because the company uses Sage 200 for accounting.  I already have a solid solution for that winxp in a virtual box.  The other is connecting to an MSSQL database, but I am beginning to learn that connecting using JTDS though its rather slow to connect on Libreoffice.